# Python 2.7.9: list of dictionaries, calculating mean and std

Tags: python, list, dictionary, std, mean

Using Python 2.7.9: I have a list of dictionaries that hold a 'data' item, how do I access each item into a list so I may get the mean and standard deviation? Here's an example:

```
values = [{'colour': 'b.-', 'data': 12.3}, {'colour': 'b.-', 'data': 11.2}, {'colour': 'b.-', 'data': 9.21}]
```

So far I have:

```
val = []
for each in values:
    val.append(each.items()[1][1])
print np.mean(val) # gives 10.903
print np.std(val)  # gives 1.278
```

Crude and not very Pythonic(?)

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension is probably easiest. You can extract the numbers like this:

```
numbers = [x['data'] for x in values]
```

Then you just call numpys mean/std/etc functions on that, just like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for (perhaps) an unnecessary question, I've seen this:

[average list of dictionaries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395018/average-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)

```
vals = [i['data'] for i in values]
np.mean(vals) # gives 10.903 
np.std(vals)  # gives 1.278
```

(Pythonic solution?)

Comment: Joel Hinz, thanks anyway yes I'd seen the same solution

Answer (score 0):

It is an exceptionally bad idea to index into a dictionary since it has no guarantee of order. Sometimes the 'data' element could be first, sometimes it could be second. There is no way to know without checking.

When using a dictionary, you should almost always access elements by using the key. In dictionary notation, this is `{ key:value, ... }` where each key is "unique". I can't remember the exact definition of "unique" for a python dictionary key, but it believe it is the (type, hash) pair of your object or literal.

Keeping this in mind, we have the more pythonic:

```
val = []
for data_dict in values:
  val.append(data_dict['data'])
```

If you want to be fancy, you can use a list completion which is a fancy way of generating a list from a more complex statement.

```
val = [data_dict['data'] for data_dict in values]
```

To be even more fancy, you can add a few conditionals so check for errors.

```
val = [data_dict['data'] for data_dict in values if (data_dict and 'data' in data_dict)]
```

What this most-fancy way of doing thing is doing is filtering the results of the `for data_dict in values` iteration with `if (data_dict and 'data' in data_dict)` so that the only `data_dict` instances you use in `data_dict['data']` are the ones that pass the if-check.

Answer (score 0):

You want a pythonic one Liner?

```
data = [k['data'] for k in values]
print("Mean:\t"+ str(np.mean(data)) + "\nstd :\t" + str(np.std(data)))
```

you could use the one liner

```
print("Mean:\t"+ str(np.mean([k['data'] for k in values])) + "\nstd :\t" + str(np.std([k['data'] for k in values])))
```

but there really is no point, as both print

```
Mean:   10.9033333333
std :   1.27881021092
```

and the former is more readable.